# Angular2 get existing validators of a formcontrol

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Lets say

```
surname = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]);
```

At some point depending on the situation I may add or delete any validators on surname control.

At the end How do I know what validators exists on surname control? I couldn't find any thing in documentation nor by dumping the control into console

Something like

```
surname.getValidators() should return - ['required', 'minLength']
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Reading validators from a control is currently not supported

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13461

Comment: is it still the same scenario in angular 5

Comment: The issue is still open

Comment: It's worth mentioning that buried in that long guthub issue link, there is [at least a partial solution](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13461#issuecomment-340368046) available that isn't too bad....

Answer (score 1):

You can display error messages like this:

```
onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if (!this.heroForm) { return; }
    const form = this.heroForm;
    for (const field in this.formErrors) {
            // clear previous error message (if any)
            this.formErrors[field] = '';
            const control = form.get(field);
            if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
            const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
            for (const key in control.errors) {
                this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
            }
        }
    }
}
formErrors = {
    'name': '',
    'power': ''
};
validationMessages = {
    'name': {
        'required':      'Name is required.',
        'minlength':     'Name must be at least 4 characters long.',
        'maxlength':     'Name cannot be more than 24 characters long.',
        'forbiddenName': 'Someone named "Bob" cannot be a hero.'
    },
    'power': {
        'required': 'Power is required.'
    }
};
```

Refer: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#reactive-component-template

Answer (score 0):

[Günter Zöchbauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43256622/127826) is still correct in Angular 6, but there is a workaround that works well for me.

My workaround depend on two observations:

First, you can see which validations are presently failing, by looking the keys on the `errors` object. So if you have `Validators.required` and `Validators.minLength` specified, the errors object would look like this:

```
{ required: true, minlenght: { ... } }
```

That's good enough for a lot of use cases, when you don't really care if a validator exists but doesn't prevent form submission.

Second, it turns out Angular will create validators to match the attributes set on your input. So for standard validators, my suggestion would be to **not specify the validator at all**.

Do something like this instead:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="surname" [required]="surnameRequired">
```

In your form declaration:

```
form = this.formBuilder.group({
  surname: '',
  anotherField: ['', Validators.required],
  yetAnotherField: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

And then set the value of `surnameRequired` to add or remove the validator.

I have a [working StackBlitz](https://dynamic-valiators.stackblitz.io).

My approach doesn't work for custom validators, but the bulk of my use cases don't use those. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different need to read existing validators on a form control. I have some code that is dynamically applying validators and I want some unit tests to make sure that it's doing what it's supposed to. But since you can't read validators, you're kind of screwed.

This is what I needed up doing:

```
  /**
   * Validates that Validators.requires is applied ...
   */
  it('should have a validator of required ...', () => {
    component.functionThatShouldApplyValidator(true);
    // Set the form control with an invalid value
    component.formCtrl.setValue('');
    // Expect the control to have an error { required: true }
    expect(component.formCtrl.errors.required).toBeTrue();
  });
```

Kind of a long way of doing it, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check whether a form control has some validator on it or not, you can do the following:

For angular built in validators you can use:

```
if(control.validator == Validators.required)
```

For a custom validator it will not work and you can use this workaround:

```
if(control.validator.toString() == customValidator().toString())
```

Comment: How does this handle multiple validators? Suppose I have `email: [''[Validators.required, Validators.email]]`, then I probably can't check for both, right?

Comment: yes, seems you are right :-( , I only had this need for controls with one validation...